# Docker image already pushed issue?

Tags: docker, dockerhub, docker-registry

I pulled ubuntu image on docker and made some changes to that image and commited that image and pushed back to my docker hub registry.
While pushing the image on my docker hub registry for some layer it says image already pushed skipping.
Why is it saying like this??

Help me!!

Answer (score 1):

When you make a change to the image, you're only adding a new layer. All the layers from the original image remain unchanged so they don't need to be re-pushed.

Check out https://docs.docker.com/introduction/understanding-docker/#how-does-a-docker-image-work

Comment: @@coreyob, But i dont have any image on my docker hub then while pushing any image why it say image already pushed skipping

Answer (score 0):

I think - it is for the image which is push now it has the same tag as previous.

Try again by `change/upgrade` the image tag of your.

Comment: @@David,but i am pushing it on my docker hub where i don't have any other repo

Comment: You say - you pull a image and update it. After that it push to docker hub registry. 
Firstly, use docker login and then try to push after change the image tag. lets try.

Comment: @@david I pulled Image first from some other docker hub and made changes in it and pushed the new image on my docker hub account using login

Comment: @@David ,while pushing image why it show image already pushed skipping,cause i dont have any image earlier on my docker hub

Comment: Check your docker hub account on the repository section. is there any ubuntu image previously?

Comment: @@David , I dont have

Comment: Ok, do you change the tag of your new image before pushing ? If you not, then give a try.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90549/discussion-between-david-weston-and-gaurav).